# why if and else conditions are executing at the same time? (c++)

Tags: c++, if-statement

The program is unfinished but basically what it is suppose to do is take input from the user asking them to enter sales total and a discount will be applied depending on the total. If total is greater than 200, multiple discounts are applied. Under 200, only one is applied. I run the program and both conditions execute, can't figure out why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
string rewardLevel;                                 // string called "rewardLevel" is declared
double salesTotal,
       goldDiscount,                                 
       silverDiscount,
       bronzeDiscount,
       goldExtraDiscount,
       silverExtraDiscount,
       bronzeExtraDiscount;

cout << "Please enter your current reward level: ";     // Output is displayed
cin >> rewardLevel;                                     // User is prompted 

if (rewardLevel == "G") {                               // If statement is declared 
    cout << "Enter the total amount before discount: ";
    cin >> salesTotal;
    if (salesTotal > 200) {
       double newTotal,
              additionalDiscount,
              finalTotal;
       
       goldDiscount = (salesTotal * 12) / 100;
       newTotal = salesTotal - goldDiscount;
       additionalDiscount = (newTotal * 3.50) / 100;
       finalTotal = newTotal - additionalDiscount;
       cout << "Your total after discount is: $" << finalTotal;
       
    } else (salesTotal <= 200); {
        double newTotal;
        goldDiscount = (salesTotal * 12) / 100;
        newTotal = salesTotal - goldDiscount;
        cout << "Your total after discount is: $" << newTotal;
        
    }
    
}
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
if (salesTotal > 200) {
... // do A
}
else (salesTotal <= 200); {
... // do B
}
```

Look at this line. You shouldn't add anything between `else` and `{`, as `else` means the *rest* of the situation. Perhaps the compiler gives you errors, and you add a semicolon after it.

In fact, this code means:

If `salesTotal` is greater than `200`, then do `A`. Otherwise, ***execute*** `salesTotal <= 200`. After that, always do `B`.

You should change it to this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
string rewardLevel;                                 // string called "rewardLevel" is declared
double salesTotal,
       goldDiscount,                                 
       silverDiscount,
       bronzeDiscount,
       goldExtraDiscount,
       silverExtraDiscount,
       bronzeExtraDiscount;

cout << "Please enter your current reward level: ";     // Output is displayed
cin >> rewardLevel;                                     // User is prompted 

if (rewardLevel == "G") {                               // If statement is declared 
    cout << "Enter the total amount before discount: ";
    cin >> salesTotal;
    if (salesTotal > 200) {
       double newTotal,
              additionalDiscount,
              finalTotal;
       
       goldDiscount = (salesTotal * 12) / 100;
       newTotal = salesTotal - goldDiscount;
       additionalDiscount = (newTotal * 3.50) / 100;
       finalTotal = newTotal - additionalDiscount;
       cout << "Your total after discount is: $" << finalTotal;
       
    } else { // note here
        double newTotal;
        goldDiscount = (salesTotal * 12) / 100;
        newTotal = salesTotal - goldDiscount;
        cout << "Your total after discount is: $" << newTotal;
        
    }
    
}
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is to say, the code following `else` can be either a single statement (with `;`) or some statements between `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Typo error. There is an extra `;` on the line `} else (salesTotal <= 200); {` which so corresponds to an else statement with an empty scope. The following scope is thus executed no matter what.

Comment: Without the semicolon it would simply be a syntax error.